# Run a script automatically when booting a live version of Ubuntu form a USB stick

Tags: 16.04, usb, live-usb, startup, bashrc

I have a Ubuntu install USB stick. I never use it to actually install Ubuntu, I always select the live option (no install). Now there are multiple commands that I always have to run once it has completely booted up. I'm looking for a sort of .bashrc file on the USB stick that always gets executed once the system is up and ready. I read a lot about preseed files, but from what I understand, all that stuff only applies if you're actually installing Ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Any ideas?

Comment: Another option would be to leave space on your Live disk for installed apps, then install crontab and have it run scripts upon startup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mkusb` to create a persistent live bootable ubuntu usb. After that, just add your script under `Startup Applications`.

It will remember these changes at your next boot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good page about [LiveCD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), which is what you probably want.

When building the new LiveCD, you can treat the startup issue like you would a normal install, and edit your `/etc/rc.local` to include the commands you want to run on every boot. Make sure that you don't include `sudo` commands, and it has to exit successfully.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an /etc directory on the USB stick.

Comment: If you follow the steps in that link, the `etc` dir will be under the `edit/etc` dir of the downloaded iso.